# Knockout is returning some weird code instead of my string

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

```
    `self.affiliateDescription = ko.observable();

    self.connectedTo = ko.computed(function() {
      return self.app.translate.get("connectedTo") + ": " + self.affiliateDescription;
    });

I assigned affiliateDescription here:
getDataPromise()
      .then(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
       //fetches data from an API and returns a JSON string
              var description = result[0].Description;
              self.affiliateDescription = JSON.stringify(description);
              console.log(self.affiliateDescription); //string prints fine here.
        }
      });`
`
```

when I go about and update affiliateDescription, I print it in the console and get the string that I desire, but the connectedTo computed string is "connected to: and then self.affiliateDescription" gives me a bunch of garbage non-sense code?

It places this garbage where my string should be on the web page:
function observable() { if (arguments.length > 0) { // Write // Ignore writes if the value hasn't changed if (observable.isDifferent(observable[observableLatestValue], arguments[0])) { observable.valueWillMutate(); observable[observableLatestValue] = arguments[0]; observable.valueHasMutated(); } return this; // Permits chained assignments } else { // Read ko.dependencyDetection.registerDependency(observable); // The caller only needs to be notified of changes if they did a "read" operation return observable[observableLatestValue]; } }

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling that observable; as in: `self.affiliateDescription()`?

Comment: I tried that, I just get an undefined for some reason. I don't get it, I explicitly assigned my string to this affiliateDescription, which I saw printed in my console

Comment: We need to see more code. Specifically how you're setting `affiliateDescription`.

Comment: basically I fetch a JSON string from a promise, then I assign the specific result from this json string into a variable called description. I print it out just fine here, but when I assigned it to affiliateDescription, it doesn't show up for some reason.

Comment: As above, you need to call your observable to set it, but this time passing its new value as a parameter instead of just overwriting it like you are now. `self.affiliateDescription(JSON.stringify(description));`

Comment: That did the trick! Lifesaver! JohnnyHK++

Comment: Have you gone through the [Knockout.js Tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/)? I strongly suggest going through that to get a better handle on the fundamental concepts like this.

Comment: I have a while back, it just slipped my mind the way to assign things.

Comment: No worries; glad you got it working. I'll close this as a dupe as it's a common question.

Comment: sounds good, thanks again!